# Using sed on a string that contains reg expressions

Tags: sed

I'm trying to do a find/replace and an insert with sed but I keep getting a message that says "extra characters at the end of n command." I'm also not running this from the terminal, it's embedded in a shell script so I can send it to others.

This is what I'm trying to run

```
sed -i 's/include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;/# include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;/g' ~/Documents/test.conf;
sed '$a; include "/etc/racoon/remote/*.conf" ;/g' ~/Documents/test.conf;
```

To make it easier to see, I'm trying to replace

```
include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;
```

with

```
# include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;
```

and then add this

```
include "/etc/racoon/remote/*.conf" ;
```

Basically, I just want to comment out the last line of a file and then insert a line after it. I'm pretty new to sed so I'm not sure if I'm going about this all wrong, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody runs into this problem, you either have to download gnu-sed or do it by other means.

You can download gnu-sed easily if you have Homebrew installed.

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

Or you can use perl and printf like I did

To do the replacement

```
sudo perl -pi -e 's|include "/var/run/racoon/\*.conf" ;|# include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;|g' /etc/racoon/racoon.conf;
```

To add a line. It will always be line 139 for me so I could go this route.

```
line='include "/etc/racoon/remote/*.conf" ;'
sudo printf '%s\n' H 139i "$line" . wq | ed -s /etc/racoon/racoon.conf
```

Thank you to devnull for helping me get my syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 problems with what you're trying:

- You need to use different delimiters since your pattern and replacement contain `/`.  You can use `|`.
- The `*` in the pattern needs to be escaped, `\*`.

As such, the first expression would look like:

```
sed -i 's|include "/var/run/racoon/\*.conf" ;|# include "/var/run/racoon/*.conf" ;|g' ~/Documents/test.conf;
```

Similarly, change the second one.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had tried that but it didn't work for me. Turns out my real problem was I didn't have gnu sed installed, which is what allows the -i option.